# Can not find data of html with R

Tags: html, r

I want to import a table with R, but I cannot find it.

```
library(rvest)
XXX <- read_html('http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/anleihen/kurshistorie/Inh-Schv_v20122019-Anleihe-2019-AT0000A0U9J2/FSE/1.5.2017_19.11.2018#Kurshistorie')
```

Thats my code for the website, I am searching for the huge table, called "Historische Kurse Scholz Holding". I cannot find the data in XXX, but i can find it when I use the Inspector on the website directly. Why is it so? Any suggestions how to extract the data with R?

Edit: Copy paste is not an option, I have to do this with 1000 webpages.

Best regards

Edit:

URL_1<- structure(list(carb = c('000A0U9J2', '000A0V7D8', '000A0VL70', '000A0VLS5'), optden = c('http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/anleihen/kurshistorie/Inh-Schv_v20122019-Anleihe-2019-AT0000A0U9J2/FSE/1.5.2017_19.11.2018#Kurshistorie',
                                                                                                'http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/anleihen/kurshistorie/Strabag_SEEO-Schuldverschr_201219-Anleihe-2019-AT0000A0V7D8/FSE/1.5.2017_19.11.2018#Kurshistorie', 'http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/anleihen/kurshistorie/BorealisEO-Schuldv_201219-Anleihe-2019-AT0000A0VL70/FSE/1.5.2017_19.11.2018#Kurshistorie', 'http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/anleihen/kurshistorie/AndritzEO-Anleihe_201219-Anleihe-2019-AT0000A0VLS5/FSE/1.5.2017_19.11.2018#Kurshistorie')), .Names = c("ISIN", "LINK"
                                                                                                ), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: would you kindly provide the package you are using (`read_html`)

Comment: Sorry, i am using rvest

Comment: This is a very complex site that uses XHR requests to load that HTML `<div>` with the price table. It's also using something called "ajax tokens" to make it harder to do this very task. Those tokens are generated anew each page and get passed with the XHR `POST` request that asynchronously retrieves the table. You should consider using RSelenium or splashr, both of which use full browser environments to render content. It's possible to eventually work up a solution without using RSelenium or splashr but it will be a tedious journey.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution involving `RSelenium` via `docker` (more information can be found [here](https://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker)). First, a few preliminaries:

1. In the `docker` terminal

   ```
   docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0
   ```
2. In `R`

   ```
   remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L)
   remDr$open(silent = T)
   ```

Now we can navigate to the page and extract the table

```
url1 <- "http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/anleihen/kurshistorie/Inh-Schv_v20122019-Anleihe-2019-AT0000A0U9J2/FSE/1.5.2017_19.11.2018#Kurshistorie"
remDr$navigate(url1)
pageSource <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
dt <- html_table(html_nodes(pageSource, ".table"), fill = T)
```

And here is the result

```
# printing the head of the data frame
> head(dt[[7]])
       Datum Eröffnung Schluss Tageshoch Tagestief Umsatz   
1 19.11.2018    1,5000  1,5000    1,5000    1,5000  1.000 NA
2 16.11.2018    1,5000  1,5000    1,5000    1,5000     NA NA
3 15.11.2018    1,5000  1,5000    1,5000    1,5000     NA NA
4 14.11.2018    1,5000  1,5000    1,5000    1,5000  2.000 NA
5 13.11.2018    1,5000  1,5000    1,5000    1,5000     NA NA
6 12.11.2018    1,2500  2,2500    2,2500    1,2500  1.127 NA
```

**Addendum**

As indicated in the link [above](https://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker), here is how to get started with `RSelenium` and `docker`:

- Install `docker`
- Pull an image, e.g. (in the `docker` terminal) `docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0`
- Now one can proceed with 1. and 2. above

Comment: So, I want to extend the whole stuff with a while loop, but my one is not working, and the solutions which are given back are unconstant anf often zero. Is it passible to do this R code a few thousand times in a row? I have edit a data set with 4 rows for which I am trying to do a while loop.

Comment: @Kramer `RSelenium` is unfortunately unstable at times and rather slow. To avoid errors you might need to add some `sys.Sleep()` in order to let the page load. Also, what you might want to consider wrapping the scrapping process in a `try()` in order to handle errors e.g. `for(k in seq(1000)) res <- try(myScrapper(url[k]))` (and maybe also a `while` loop in order to try multiple times if the attempt fails).

Comment: @Kramer Also, to state the obvious, check that for all links the above code works, i.e. that it indeed gathers the relevant data.